# Ask about the usage of the tilde '~'sign

Tags: newtags

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ask about the usage of the tilde '~'sign

what's the difference between :

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('~cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=5)
```

and:

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=5)
```

By the way, what's the `queue_size` in the bracket mean?

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250092/ask-about-the-usage-of-the-tilde-%27%7E%27sign/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tilde is due to [namespacing](http://wiki.ros.org/Names). a `~` puts a topic or a parameter in the nodes private namespace (i.e. `/some_ns/node_ns/private_topic`), whereas without the tilde, it resides in the nodes namespace (i.e. `/some_ns/topic`). If you add a `/` instead of the tilde, you'll end up in the global namespace (`/topic`).

Python does not have the concept of a [NodeHandle as C++](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles), but in essence this is the same as `ros::NodeHandle nh("~")`, `ros::NodeHandle nh("")` and `ros::NodeHandle nh("/")`.

About the queue_size, there is a good explanation on the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#queue_size:_publish.28.29_behavior_and_queuing).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7